# Security Exception while connecting using sftp through JSCH

Tags: java, security, exception, cryptography, jsch

I am getting this error while creating SFTP with JSCH.
I am trying to connect to a remote server via sftp to transfer files but while calling connect method below error occurs.

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at javax.crypto.Cipher.getInstance(DashoA13*..)
at com.jcraft.jsch.jce.AES256CTR.init(AES256CTR.java:56)
at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.checkCipher(Session.java:2072)
at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.checkCiphers(Session.java:2049)
at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.send_kexinit(Session.java:592)
at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:286)
at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:162)
at scb.frame.runner.ServerSetup.contactServer(ServerSetup.java:56)

Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Cannot set up certs for trusted CAs
at javax.crypto.SunJCE_b.<clinit>(DashoA13*..)
... 34 more
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Cannot locate policy or framework files!
at javax.crypto.SunJCE_b.i(DashoA13*..)
at javax.crypto.SunJCE_b.g(DashoA13*..)
at javax.crypto.SunJCE_b$1.run(DashoA13*..)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
... 35 more
```

**My Code to Connect :**

```
    String host = serverProperties.getProperty("Host");
    String username = serverProperties.getProperty("Username");
    String password = serverProperties.getProperty("Password");
        JSch jsch = new JSch();
        Security.addProvider(new com.sun.crypto.provider.SunJCE());
        Session session;
        try {
            session = jsch.getSession(username, host, 22);

        session.setPassword(password);

        Properties config = new Properties();
        config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        session.setConfig(config);
        session.connect();
        ChannelSftp sftpChannel = (ChannelSftp) session.openChannel("sftp");
        sftpChannel.connect();
        sftpChannel.get(sourceFile,destFile);
```

Command line version of Same Program I am able to run without any exception!
also example of SFTP from Jcraft[link]http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/Sftp.java.html website is running perfectly.

Comment: Can a known working program connect via SFTP to your server? Can a known working program connect via FTP? Can you modify your program to work with FTP. (I'm not saying ditch security, I'm just saying to test similar tasks first)

Comment: @supersam654 FTP has no relation to the issue (at all - this is a completely different protocol).

Comment: @supersam654 Do you know a s/w called WINSCP.This s/w uses sftp,scp to connect to the server to transfer files.I want to do the same. There are other lot of s/w available which let you connect through sftp.

Comment: @WitVault right, can you connect successfully with WINSCP to the server in question?  He wants to rule out the possibility that it's your server that's the issue and not your code. And can you post what your connection code looks like?

Comment: @PeterElliott Yes offcourse I am currently using WINSCP for the transfer the files to server.

Comment: `JSch jsch = new JSch();
   Security.addProvider(new com.sun.crypto.provider.SunJCE());
   Session session;
   try {
    session = jsch.getSession(username, host, 22);

   session.setPassword(password);

   Properties config = new Properties();
   config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
   session.setConfig(config);
   session.connect();`

Comment: please edit your answer to add the code instead of posting it as a comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has to do with Java's security restrictions. By default, there is a restricted key size of 128 bits. From your stacktrace, I see you're trying to use an AES 256 bit encryption.

To solve your problem, go to Java's website and download the Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html

(to be found at the bottom)

Install them in your JRE and you are good to go :) All thanks to US government...

Comment: verhage:I am developing an application to run on any system. do I need to install these policy files on each system(which is some what impossible) or is there any way to include in the application itself so that it can run smoothly ?

Comment: I'm afraid so. Or you could cut down on security and use a smaller key (<= 128 bits).

Comment: @verhage, Strangely, as of 2009 there were indications that [256b AES is not that much better than 128b](http://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2009/07/another_new_aes.html), though you really shouldn't let deployment concerns dictate key size.  If you're out of other options, I'd look into using a URLClassLoader and reflection to get signed jars with the full version of JCE dynamically on first run.

Comment: @MikeSamuel:I am able to run console version of the same program,also the example of sftp from JSCH Jcraft website[link]http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/Sftp.java.html

Comment: @WitValue, then you're in luck.  Dump the environment variables from both runs and figure out which ones differ and which of those differences affects your program.  Worst-case, you'll have to write a java wrapper that uses `Runtime.exec` or `CommandBuilder` to run your main java class with different environment variables.

Comment: In jdk1.8.0_161 and forward, unlimited cryptography strength is enabled by default. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8u161-relnotes-4021379.html#JDK-8170157